# TCP server truncate readed message from networkstream

Tags: json, vb.net, buffer, tcplistener

I have implemented a TCP listener like this:

```
Using client As TcpClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient()

                Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf NewClient)

                Using ns As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()

                    While ns.DataAvailable

                        Dim toReceive(100000) As Byte

                        Dim length As Integer = ns.Read(toReceive, 0, toReceive.Length)

                        If length > My.Settings.minLenghtForSuccess Then
                            Dim text As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(toReceive, 0, length)
                            text = "{" & text.Split("{")(1)
                            Dim jsonObj As Object = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(text)
                            Dim ipOrigine As String = ""
                            Dim dispositivoOrigine As String = ""
                            Dim canaleOrigine As String = ""
                            Dim targa As String = ""
                            Dim frontespizio = jsonObj("data")(0)
                            ipOrigine = frontespizio("IPAddress")
                            dispositivoOrigine = frontespizio("DeviceName")
                            canaleOrigine = frontespizio("ChannelName")
                            targa = frontespizio("PicData")(0)("PlateInfo")(0)("SnapId")

                        End If
                        'Console.WriteLine(text)
                        'Console.WriteLine()

                        'Dim toSend() As Byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Message Received...")

                        'ns.Write(toSend, 0, toSend.Length)

                    End While

                End Using

            End Using
```

When it receive a message from the client it gets truncated and I don't know why. I think it's for toReceive(100000) var. How can I solve this?
My incoming message is something like:

> POST /API/AlarmEvent/EventPush
>
> HTTP/1.1 Host: 192.168.2.103:123
>
> Accept: */*
>
> Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
>
> Content-Length: 106438
>
> {"result":"success","data":{"EventType":"LPD","EventTime":"2015-1-15
> 9:53:39","EventAction":"start","ChannelName":"PERGENOVA","DeviceName":"BS-IPT4704G3MZ+","IPAddress":"192.168.2.168","MacAddress":"00-23-63-92-25-47","PicData":{"PlateInfo":[{"Id":"","GrpId":3,"SnapId":"AH234MG","Type":10,"StrChn":"CH1","StartTime":1421315612,"EndTime":1421315656,"Chn":0,"Sex":0,"PlateColor":0,"CarBrand":"","CarType":"","Owner":"","IdCode":"","Job":"","Phone":"","Domicile":"","Remark":"","PlateImg":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAdgB2AAD/7wAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/bAEMAAwICAwICAwMDAwQDAwQFCAUFBAQFCgcHBggMCgwMCwoLCw0OEhANDhEOCwsQFhARExQVFRUMDxcYFhQYEhQVFP/bAEMBAwQEBQQFCQUFCRQNCw0UFB="}]}}}

- PlateImg is very long, over 100000 byte and its lenght is not fixed

Comment: It could be due to the fixed size of the `toReceive` buffer. you initialized `toReceive` with a fixed size of 100,000 bytes, if the incoming message is larger than that, it will get truncated as you observed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be due to the fixed size of the `toReceive` buffer. you initialized `toReceive` with a fixed size of 100,000 bytes, if the incoming message is larger than that, it will get truncated as you observed.

Try using a dynamic buffer instead.

e.g.

```
Using client As TcpClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient()
    Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf NewClient)

    Using ns As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
        Dim buffer As New MemoryStream() ' Use MemoryStream as a dynamic buffer

        Dim bytesRead As Integer
        Dim receiveBuffer(4096) As Byte ' Buffer to read incoming data in chunks

        Do
            bytesRead = ns.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length)
            If bytesRead > 0 Then
                buffer.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
            End If
        Loop While bytesRead > 0

        buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) ' Reset the position of the MemoryStream

        Dim receivedData(buffer.Length) As Byte
        buffer.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length)

        ' Now you have the complete message in the receivedData array as bytes.

        Dim text As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData)
        ' Rest of your code to process the message...

    End Using
End Using
```

Using `MemoryStream` as dynamic buffer, you can read the incoming data in chunks (*4096 bytes in this case*) and append it to the buffer until there is no more data to read. Then, you can convert the `MemoryStream` content to a byte array and proceed with processing the received message.